# How to create an installer with no standard form in the visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer

I need to create an installer for my application. I created a setup project. I clicked on it with the right mouse button - View - User interface. Then I pressed the right mouse button on the item "Start" - Add Dialog. I need a five-RadioButton form, but only four are offered. How can I create a form with five RadioButtons?

Comment: How did you create your setup project? Use a vs extension or a third party tool?

Comment: No. This is a standard tool. Add - New Project - Other project type - Setup and Deployment - Visual studio installer - Setup project

Comment: I have a solution and you can check my answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a five-RadioButton form, but only four are offered. How can I
>   create a form with five RadioButtons?

**Actually**, it can be done and I have test the function in my side and get what you want as it shows:

[image]

You can try my following steps:

**Solution**

**1)** download the zip file under [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18834/Create-custom-dialogs-for-use-in-your-Visual-Studi), unpack the zip file and get the folder called `customdialogsvsd_src`.

**2)** copy the file from the download folder `customdialogsvsd_src\VsdDialogs\0\MMCustom5ButtonDlg.wid` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment\VsdDialogs\0`

Then:

copy the file `customdialogsvsd_src\VsdDialogs\1033\MMCustom5ButtonDlg.wid` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment\VsdDialogs\1033`

**Note**: please make sure that the current OS account has the privilege to modify the local Visual Studio 10's folder.

**3)** then restart your VS2010 and you can add the dialog five-radiobutton form in setup projects.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Many thanks! You really helped me =)
Just in case, I note that if visual studio has Russian localization, then this solution will not work